# Why can't I see UIStackView in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I'm going to put UIStackView in UIScrollView. To put it easier, I'm going to make a mind map. The UIStackView I put into UIScrollView is an object of mind map. Thus, The embedded UIStackView will appear in all zones of UIScrollView.

However, although I have specified the location of UIStackView for UIScrollView, UIStackView does not appear in UIScrollView.

**My interface builder(Attaches an interface builder image to understand the My View hierarchy.):**

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var createObject: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let redView = UIView()
        redView.backgroundColor = .red

        let blueView = UIView()
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [redView, blueView])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

        stackView.center = scrollView.center

        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your image shows you are getting constraint errors. Show those errors.

Comment: @DonMag Hello, Thank you for your comment. The image I showed you was to understand the view hierarchy in my interface builder. Interface builder or my code did not have an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `UIView` nor `UIStackView` have intrinsic sizes.

So you end up adding a stack view of size `0, 0` containing two views, each sized `0, 0`, to your scroll view.

You need to apply some sizing somewhere.

This will give you a stack view that is equal width to your scroll view, and twice as tall (so you have a "full-height" blue view and a a "full-height" red view):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let redView = UIView()
        redView.backgroundColor = .red

        let blueView = UIView()
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [redView, blueView])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2.0),
            ])

    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Here is another example. It adds 6 subviews, with specified widths and heights. The stack view properties are changed to:

```
.alignment = .center
.distribution = .fill
.spacing = 8
```

The result:

[image]

and scrolled down:

[image]

and the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .red,
            .blue,
            .green,
            .orange,
            .yellow,
            .cyan,
        ]

        let sizes: [CGSize] = [
            CGSize(width: 100, height: 150),
            CGSize(width: 250, height: 100),
            CGSize(width: 200, height: 120),
            CGSize(width: 160, height: 200),
            CGSize(width: 220, height: 180),
            CGSize(width:  60, height:  80),
        ]

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.spacing = 8

        for (color, size) in zip(colors, sizes) {
            let v = UIView()
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
            v.backgroundColor = color
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // do NOT set a heightAnchor ... let the subviews define the height
//          stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2.0),
            ])

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your sincere reply.
Can I ask you a few more questions?

The current UIStackView fills the ScrollView screen. But I don't want to fill it up, I want it to be like an image of a revised question. Can I specify the frame size of UIStackView?

Comment: And I don't want to change the size ratio of internal Views according to UIStackView frame size. I hope all VIews will have their own size, as shown in the picture attached to the link below. [link](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/82128953f6/uistack_hero_2x_04e50947-5aa0-4403-825b-26ba4c1662bd.png)

Comment: You can apply any sizing you want. Your image, though, appears to be showing a *horizontal* arrangement, while your question specified `.vertical` for the .`axis` of your stack view?

Comment: If you're talking about the [link] I just sent you, it's just an example for sizing of each arranged subviews. Your vertical arrangement is right. Do you happen to know how to specify the size I want?

Comment: First, I want to adjust the size of UIStackView.

Comment: Do you know the sizes you want for your subviews?

Comment: Yes. But, I want know how to adjust frame of the UIStackView firstly.

Comment: Just change the `.heightAnchor` to be the height you want, instead of it being 2 * the height of the scroll view. However, if you have `.distribution` set to `.fillEqually`, then all of the subviews you add will have the same height.

Comment: Thanks to you, my problem has been solved, thank you very much for your kindness in my poor English. I remember you!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set frame to stackview. Try adding

```
stackView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

after addSubview.